# javascript/ajax loading and preloading images

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am very new at this. I have to write a photo album using ajax. Upon clicking a link from a list of links, an image will show up and at the same time preload the previous and next images so they will open faster when clicked. Either load them asynchronously or synchronously. 
After the next photo is revealed, the previous photo should be automatically hidden. Only one photo should be displayed at any given time.
I was looking at writing a for loop in the javascript portion, is that the best way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<p id="Title">text</p>
<p id="Body">text
</p>

<p class="background">&nbsp;</p>

<p class="link1"><a href="image1.jpg">Photo 1</a> </p>
<p class="link2"><a href="image2.jpg">Photo 2</a> </p>
<p class="link3"><a href="image3.jpg">Photo 3</a></p>
<p class="link4"><a href="image4.jpg">Photo 4</a></p>
<p class="link5"><a href="image5.jpg">Photo 5</a> </p>
<p class="link6"><a href="image6.jpg">Photo 6</a> </p>
<p class="link7"><a href="image7.jpg">Photo 7</a> </p>
<p class="link8"><a href="image8.jpg">Photo 8</a> </p>
<p class="link9"><a href="image9.jpg">Photo 9</a> </p>
<p class="link10"><a href="image10.jpg">Photo 10</a> </p>
<p class="link11"><a href="image11.jpg">Photo 11</a> </p>
<p class="link12"><a href="image12.jpg">Photo 12</a> </p>
<p class="link13"><a href="image13.jpg">Photo 13</a> </p>
<p class="link14"><a href="image14.jpg">Photo 14</a> </p>
<p class="link15"><a href="image15.jpg">Photo 15</a> </p>
<p class="link16"><a href="image16.jpg">Photo 16</a> </p>
<p class="link17"><a href="image17.jpg">Photo 17</a> </p>
<p class="link18"><a href="image18.jpg">Photo 18</a> </p>
<p class="link19"><a href="image19.jpg">Photo 19</a> </p>
<p class="link20"><a href="image20.jpg">Photo 20</a> </p>

<script>


var images= new Array()
    images[0]="image1.jpg";
    images[1]="image2.jpg";
    images[2]="image3.jpg";
    images[3]="image4.jpg";
    images[4]="image5.jpg";
    images[5]="image6.jpg";
    images[6]="image7.jpg";
    images[7]="image8.jpg";
    images[8]="image9.jpg";
    images[9]="image10.jpg";
    images[10]="image11.jpg";
    images[11]="image12.jpg";
    images[12]="image13.jpg";
    images[13]="image14.jpg";
    images[14]="image15.jpg";
    images[15]="image16.jpg";
    images[16]="image17.jpg";
    images[17]="image18.jpg";
    images[19]="image19.jpg";
    images[20]="image20.jpg";

var numImages = images.length;
var count = 0;
function preloadImage()
{
    i=images[];
    for(i=0;i<=numImages; i++)
    images[i].onclick=preload(images[i+1];
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To preload images to browser memory you should do that:

```
function preloadImage(url) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "url_to_image.png"; // in this moment browser will request the image
    return image; // returning handler in case you want to use it later
}
```

You may consider using some existing galleries like [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)